# What is the different ways in Photoshop to copy the remaining layers and create a new document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, layers

Basically when someone gives me a PSD that has a bunch of copy and other things that I need to quickly strip off to use the background on a web page. What are the fastest ways to clear that and start new.

Currently I save a copy. Then start deleting the layers that will not be used as web backgrounds.

But then what? I remember a keyboard shortcut in Photoshop to copy and then paste to a new document, and when copied it came down to the size of the remaining object (not the original canvas size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-Click (Windows) or Control-Click (Macintosh) on a highlighted layer or a series of highlighted layers and choose Duplicate Layer(s).... from the contextual menu.

Choose "New" from the destination drop down and click OK.

This will open a new document the same size as the original with only the layer(s) you have highlighted in the Layers Panel.

Comment: Ok, cool. I guess all the layers though were built on the same size canvas, so hard to strip out the logos for my original intended purpose. 

But your answer worked fine.

Comment: You could always use Image > Trim to crop the canvas to the size of the artwork if that's needed.